# Do I need MongoDB (or another type of database) to authenticate with Google?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, node.js, authentication, mongodb

I'm creating a web application using Node.js and Pug, and have recently been looking at adding external OAuth authentication to this site, using Express and Passport.js.

I've found a lot of examples to do this online such as:

- https://developerhandbook.com/passport.js/how-to-add-passportjs-google-oauth-strategy/
- https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth2
- https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-facebook-example/blob/master/server.js

Some of these hint at being able to do this without storing user credentials yourself in a database, while most seem to include MongoDB as standard in the set up. I was wondering if it is necessary to use MongoDB for this and if so why?

Previously I've done more data analysis type coding so I'm a little out of my depth here with all of this web design stuff. Any info or advice as to how to go about this would be very appreciated (apologies if this counts as off-topic, never visited this Stack Exchange site before)

Comment: Would appreciate if people could tell me why my question isn't a good one for this SE instead of downvoting and running away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that OAuth external authentication will give you is that you can ask Google (or Facebook or whomever) "is this JackLidge that tries to use my service the same JackJidge that signed up for it" without having to deal with the hassles of hashing passwords and securely storing them.

However, most likely your application will be storing other stuff, like user content or authorization information (what is JackLidge allowed to do within the application).

When using OAuth, you don't need a database for user credentials, but you probably do need a database for (some of) the other information you are going to store.